# how to show http response in openTelemetry/jaeger?

Tags: quarkus, open-telemetry, jaeger

I just follow this tutorial here
https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry
to create a quarkus application with openTelemetry and jaeger.

It works fine, I can see all my requests in jaeger, but there is no response body.

My problem here is that I have several microservices communication with each other and sometimes one gets an error that stops the whole process, so I have to debbug one by one to find which service did fail.
If I get this response body in jaeger this would be easily to identify which service trigger any exception.

So right now I don't have any response body in my jaeger and I don't know if jaeger doesn't show any response and I have to find another tool, or if there is some configuration I need to do in my opentelemetry to send it to jaeger.

Can someone help? There is any way to see http responses with openTelemetry?

Comment: Errors should show up automatically without any additional configuration. Can you please open an issue with a reproducer here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are making HTTP requests, on Quarkus, HTTP request spans will show the operation result:
[HTTP Span details pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX2hC.png).
If you need to add specific details about the response you might need to create a manual span for it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add it manually as attribute of current span:

```
final Span span = io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span.current();
span.setAttribute("http.response.headers", header);
span.setAttribute("http.response.body", body);
if (httpStatus >= Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode()) {
     span.setStatus(StatusCode.ERROR);
}
```

I still thinking that quarkus-opentelemetry should have an application property to define that we want header and/or body for request, response, client request and client response on Span.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using Quarkus ContainerRequestFilter to intercept all requests and Span bean provided by [quarkus-opentelemetry](https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#available-opentelemetry-cdi-injections)

So my solution looked like this:

```
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@JBossLog
public class OtelCustomInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    
    @Inject
    Span span;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        var headers = context.getHeaders();
        headers.forEach((k, l) -> l.forEach(
            header -> setSpan(k, header, span)
        ));
    }

    private static Span setSpan(String k, String header, Span span) {
        return span.setAttribute("http.request.headers.%s".formatted(k), header);
    }

}
```